# Infinite loop when read integers from line using istringstream

Tags: c++

I have a txt file with this content:

```
999
2
4 6 5 1 3 2 -1 50 50 100 500 100 500
5 6 2 4 -1 50 100 100 50
2
1
5 -1 4
1 2 -1 20 20
2
3 4 -1 40 30
```

I read this file and add the line that has a length > 1 to a vector:

```
    std::ifstream file("fake_solu.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    // skip that
    int result ;
    file >> result ;  file >> K; 
    vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    getline(file, line);
    for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i){
        getline(file, line);
    } 
    
    // this is start at line 5th (value is 2)
    file >> M; 
    cout << M <<endl;
    int start_route = 0, cnt = 0;
    getline(file, line);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i){
        // Problem starts here
        int num_drone;
        file >> num_drone; 
        getline(file, line);
        cout << "num_dron: " << num_drone << endl;

        getline(file, line); 
        vector<int> drone_trip;
        while (line.length() > 1) { 
            drone_trip = get_route(line, start_route, cnt);
            for (auto ele: drone_trip) cout << ele << " ";  cout <<endl;
            // cout << endl << cnt << " " << start_route << endl;
            getline(file, line); 
        }
        getline(file, line);
    }
```

And here is `get_route` function code

```
vector<int> get_route(string line, int &start_load, int &cnt){
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int n = 0; cnt = 0;
    std::vector<int> drone_trip;

    while (iss >> n){
        cnt++;
        if (n == -1) start_load = cnt;
        drone_trip.push_back(n);
    }
    return drone_trip;
}
```

I have problems when the last line reaches, it repeats infinitely. And `num_drone`does not change.

This is the output:

```
2
num_dron: 1
5 -1 4
1 2 -1 20 20
num_dron: 1
3 4 -1 40 30
3 4 -1 40 30 
3 4 -1 40 30
...
and so on
```

How can I stop that repeat? Basically, I want to split into clusters, the line of length 1 is the boundary.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] istead of code snippets. This may be some additional work for you, but it's the price for getting a quick answer. But anyway `while (iss >> n)` looks wrong, what is this supposed to do?

Comment: sorry, my English is not good :((.

Comment: ```while (iss >> n)``` to read number in string, (aka a line)

Comment: `while (iss >> n)` well, yes this reads a number info `n`. But when do you think the `while` loop stops?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `get_route` but with the code that calls it.

You never check whether reading is sucessful in the  `while (line.length() > 1)` loop, so if the file ends with a line with more than one character - as your example does - you reach end-of-file and the last line stays in `line` forever.

You want something more like this:

```
int num_drone;
file >> num_drone; 
cout << "num_dron: " << num_drone << endl;

// You might want to put this in a new function, as it is quite verbose. 
// Or keep using 'getline'.
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

vector<int> drone_trip;
while (getline(file, line) && line.length() > 1) { 
    drone_trip = get_route(line, start_route, cnt);
    for (auto ele: drone_trip)
        cout << ele << " ";  
    cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: I changed it so not Infinite loop but the last line ```3 4 -1 40 30```does not exist

Comment: That's because your reading is out of sync with the contents. I suspect that you left that last `getline(file, line);` after the loop in there.

Comment: if edit the same your reply, then return the output
```2 \n
num_dron: 1 \n
num_dron: 5 \n
-1 4 \n
1 2 -1 20 20 50
``` 
So I add ```getline()``` after line ```file >> num_drone```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about one of the old reading problems. The conventional way of avoiding it is to not read a "dummy" but to `ignore`.

Comment: I realize the problem.
When I read the line with length 1, it went through that line to next line, so missing the last line